# How can we require users to accept all permissions in our Facebook SSO?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there a way to simply require that any user signing up for our Facebook app to either accept ALL permissions requested or not at all? We do not want to give the options to accept certain parameters and reject others in Facebook SSO.

Answer (score 3):

If the user really doesn't want to enable certain extended permissions.  It's their choice; Facebook has spoken.

You are expected to check if the user has disabled permissions.  If so, you should provide an error message that some of your application's functionality is disabled and ask them to re-enable those permissions again.

Yes, this makes it harder for developers, but you have to accept it.

Comment: You can check what permissions you have for a given user by accessing `https://graph.facebook.com/[USERID]/permissions?access_token=...`

Answer (score 0):

First : you must try to get just permissions you need them (its facebook rule)

Second:yes you can do it, at first let users to install app with permissions which they want then check your app's permissions if user does not accepted some permissions redirect user to install page again (times & times)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions

Comment: Hello Pooya,Thank you for your help. Question for you. I came across this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#user_friends_perms

Comment: Hello Pooya,Thank you for your help. Question for you. I came across this:(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#user_friends_perms) Am I right to assume that if we just use the user and friend's permissions then the permissions are non-revokable by the user? From my reading it seems that the only times the information is revokable is if we ask for extended permissions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: user is not able to revoke permissions (just can remove the app)
expect extended permissions like (publish_stream) & in new auth dialog user should give to your application needed permissions in 2 steps first for normal permissions & then for extended permissions 
(but you can don't show application to that users who not installed your app via all permissions )
My own experience : just require permission Which you really need 
it can help you to have even 2-3 times more users for each unneeded  deleted permissions )